# Trying to automate a data pull process using python and email trigger

Tags: python, imap

I have been trying to create a python script to be run on a Linux server where it will check for a specific email in my mailbox and then trigger a sas script.

Currently, my approach is using python's imaplib. The exact steps to my approach are:

1. Email is received in my Outlook folder
2. This email is forwarded to a gmail account through Outlook trigger.
3. The gmail account is linked to python via imaplib and receives only THESE SPECIFIC EMAILS(frequency is monthly)
4. I need to create a code that will monitor the inbox of this email and trigger the sas script when there is a new email detected in gmail.

I am a noob to python and any help in this regard would be a godsend.

```
import imaplib,email
imap_server = 'imap.gmail.com'
email_id = ''
password = ''
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)
imap.login(email_id,password)
imap.select("Inbox")
imap.search(None,'ALL')
```

This is my current code. Although, when using imap.search(None,'NEW'), i'm getting an error. What should the next steps be? I want to check if there is any new email in the mailbox, if yes then trigger the sas script.

Also, please note that this python will be running in the Linux system where the sas code is present.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service or a replacement for basic documentation and tutorials. Show us the code you've written, explain where you're having problems, and we would be happy to help out.

Comment: thanks @larsks. have made the changes

Comment: When you say ' you get an error', exactly what error do you get?  Is it a stack trace?  Show us the whole stack trace.

Comment: I'm not even going to try to answer the question (I'm not a code writing service), but I'll comment: The `select` returns a number, call it n, and the `search` returns an array containing the integers 1-n inclusive.